# Apache VirtualHost not responding

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

I have two IP addresses pointing to my server Ubuntu 16.04 on DigitalOcean.

For one IP address, the following works fine.

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
  ServerName  www.mysite.com

  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  DocumentRoot /home/mysite.com

  <Directory /home/mysite.com/>
    Require all granted
    Allowoverride ALL
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I add another VirtualHost with my 2nd IP address

```
<VirtualHost 5.6.7.8:80>
  ServerName  www.mysite2.com

  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  DocumentRoot /home/mysite2.com

  <Directory /home/mysite2.com/>
    Require all granted
    Allowoverride ALL
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This doesn't work, instead, I see Ubuntu default index.html page.

I ran apache2ctl -S and this is what I see.

```
1.2.3.4:80     is a NameVirtualHost
default server www.mysite2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite2.com.conf:1)
```

So it looks like 1.2.3.4 is a NameVirtualHost and 5.6.7.8 isn't?

So I tried setting

```
NameVirtualHost 5.6.7.8:80
```

But still no luck. So I thought, perhaps I need to set the "Listen" directive. This directive was set in "ports.conf" as

```
Listen 80
```

So I tried changing it to

```
Listen 1.2.3.4:80
Listen 5.6.7.8:80
```

With no luck.

But I did get it to work by doing the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName  www.mysite2.com

  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
  DocumentRoot /home/mysite2.com

  <Directory /home/mysite2.com/>
    Require all granted
    Allowoverride ALL
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But that would be a "hacky" way of making it work since it's just.. catch-all? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If a `<VirtualHost>` block is not showing up in the output of `apachectl -S` then the file it is in is not being read by Apache. If it is in the same file as your first virtual host then something **very** strange is going on, try putting some *garbage* config in the 5.6.7.8 vhost, you should get a configuration error. Also `Listen 80` will be entirely sufficient. Also the `NameVirtualHost` directive is not required in Apachev2.4.